# tkinter progressbar for multiprocessing

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, progress-bar

I have a program that encrypts files and I used multiprocessing to make it faster, but I am having trouble with the tkinter progress bar.

I have implemented it but it completes immediately or lags in between.
The progressbar just completes to 100% but the files are still encrypting and i recieve no error.

files contains list of files.

The whole code is here - https://codeshare.io/pq8YxE

Below is the way i have implemented it.

```
def progbar():
    global pb_lable
    global percent
    global pbar
    global percentlabel
    global pbar_frame
   
    pb_lable = tk.Label(root, text='Progress', font = "Raleway 13 bold")
    pb_lable.grid(row=5, columnspan=2, sticky='w', padx=(35))

    pbar_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    pbar_frame.grid(row=6, columnspan=2)

    pbar = Progressbar(pbar_frame,orient='horizontal',length=500,mode='determinate')
    pbar.grid(row=7,column=0, pady=10, padx=20)

    percent = tk.StringVar()
    percentlabel = tk.Label(root, textvariable=percent, font='Raleway 15')
    percentlabel.grid(row=5,columnspan=2,pady=10, padx=120, sticky='w')


def encryptfn(key, a):
    f = Fernet(key)
    return f.encrypt(a)

def enc(key, process_pool, file):
    task = len(files)
    x = 0
    with open(file,'rb') as original_file:
        original = original_file.read()
    encrypted = process_pool.apply(encryptfn, args=(key, original,))
    with open (file,'wb') as encrypted_file:
        encrypted_file.write(encrypted)
    
    pbar['value']+=100/task
    x = x+1
    percent.set(str(int((x/task)*100))+'%')
    root.update_idletasks()

def encfile():
    password = bytes('asdasd', 'utf-8')
    salt = bytes('zxcasd','utf-8')
    global files
    files = filistbox.get(0,'end')

    if len(files) == 0:
        fierrorbox()
    elif len(password) == 0:
        passerrorbox()
    else:
        file_enc_button['state']='disabled'
        browsefi['state']='disabled'

        kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32,
            salt=salt,
            iterations=100,
            backend=default_backend())
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))

        MAX_THREADS = 300
        pool_size = min(MAX_THREADS, cpu_count(), len(files))
        process_pool = Pool(pool_size)
        thread_pool = ThreadPool(min(MAX_THREADS, len(files)))
        worker = partial(enc, key, process_pool)
        thread_pool.map(worker, files)

        root.event_generate("<<encryption_done>>")
        
        file_enc_button['state']='active'
        browsefi['state']='active'

def run_encfile():
    root.bind('<<encryption_done>>', encryption_done)
    Thread(target=encfile).start()

def encryption_done(*args):
    fiencdone()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    browsefi = tk.Button(root, text='Browse', command=fibrowse, borderwidth=3)
    browsefi.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)

    ##  File list  ##
    filist_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    filist_frame.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

    filistbox = tk.Listbox(filist_frame, width=40, height=10)
    filistbox.grid(row=3,columnspan=2, pady=10)

    ## Button ##
    fibutton_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    fibutton_frame.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)

    file_enc_button = tk.Button(fibutton_frame, text='Encrypt', width=15, command=run_encfile, borderwidth=3)
    file_enc_button.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=10,pady=15)

    progbar()
    percent.set('0%')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have now posted this Question several times. Could you take the time for a [mre]? You may find someone that is willing to write this code for you. Allthough, SO is for debuggin and your question lack of details. What is the expected behavior and how does it differ from it. Do you have a traceback error?

Comment: I understand that, but I wont go through all of your code to make minor changes. There is a lot of code we dont need to know. You need a window a progressbar and a process to demonstrate your issue and what you have tried to make it work. You may better ask your teacher anyway, but thats just my opinion.

Comment: what i have here is just code for encryption, the whole app is big.  i just need help implementing the progress bar thats y i created a minimal version of it - https://codeshare.io/pq8YxE

Comment: @Atlas435 can  you help me with the code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter multiprocessing progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670677/python-tkinter-multiprocessing-progress)

Comment: @Atlas435 iam having a hard time implementing it in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears with function `enc` where you keep on resetting variable `x` back to 0.

You need a global variable, for example `tasks_completed`, initialized to 0, that keeps track of the number of encryptions that have been completed and gets incremented within `enc` with the statement `tasks_completed += 1`. Technically this is equivalent to `tasks_completed = tasks_completed + 1` and is not an atomic operation and it is theoretically possible that the thread could be interrupted after reading the value of `tasks_completed` and therefore two threads would be updating `tasks_completed` to the same value. So this update, to be completely safe, should be done under control of a `multithreading.Lock` to ensure only one thread at a time can be doing the updating.

Replace function `enc` with:

```py
from threading import Lock
tasks_completed = 0

def enc(key, process_pool, lock, file):
    global tasks_completed

    with open(file,'rb') as original_file:
        original = original_file.read()
    encrypted = process_pool.apply(encryptfn, args=(key, original,))
    with open (file,'wb') as encrypted_file:
        encrypted_file.write(encrypted)
    encrypted = process_pool.apply(encryptfn, args=(key, file,))

    with lock:
        tasks_completed += 1
    percentage_completed = int((tasks_completed / len(files)) * 100)

    pbar['value'] = percentage_completed
    percent.set(f'{percentage_completed}%')
    root.update_idletasks()
```

And create a `multiprocessing.Lock` instance and pass it to `enc` in function `encfile` by modifying the function as follows:

```py
        lock = Lock() # create lock
        # add additional lock argument to enc:
        worker = partial(enc, key, process_pool, lock)
```

Comment: getting TypeError: token must be bytes and `Exception in thread Thread-1:
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:` [img](https://imgur.com/KkEXcFq)
Also the progressbar isn't moving now but the encryption is completed.

Comment: Your exception seems to have nothing to do with the progress bar but rather with encryption. Moreover, the line numbers in the stack trace do not correspond to the source you posted. As far as the progress bar not moving, see [my code](https://codeshare.io/1Y1X6z) based on your code. After the files are selected, instead of encrypting the files, `encryptfn` sleeps for 1 second and just returns the name of the file converted to upper case. I have also modified the code just to use 1 thread so if you choose 10 files the progress bar should move once every second showing 10%, 20%, 30% .... 100%..

Comment: So maybe you did not copy the code correctly.

Comment: yep, my bad missed a comma.
@Booboo the code works great. Thanks for everything. You are a life saver. Thanks again

Comment: @Booboo do you mind helping me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70378894/reading-large-file-uses-100-memory-and-my-whole-pc-frozes). Its the same code that i took from here.

Comment: @Booboo can u help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70709895/decryption-takes-more-memory-and-cpu-when-files-are-not-encrypted)