# Decryption takes more memory and CPU when files are not encrypted

Tags: python, encryption, memory

I have a file encryption/decryption program that encrypts files from a given folder. So I encrypt files and, when decrypting, if the wrong password is given, it gives an error and doesn't consume lot of memory or CPU.

However, when files are not encrypted and I try to decrypt the files, the program consumes 100% CPU and memory and throws an error of `Wrong password` (which is correct). But why des it consume so much memory and CPU?

```
def decfile(file):

    filePath, fileExtn = os.path.splitext(file)
    decFile = filePath+'dec'+fileExtn

    with open(file, 'rb') as decrypted_file:
        with open(decFile, 'wb') as original_file:
            
            nonce = decrypted_file.read(12)
            decrypted_file.seek(12)

            while True:
                l_bytes = decrypted_file.read(encrypted_blockSize)
                if not l_bytes:
                    break

                l = int.from_bytes(l_bytes, 'big')
                encrypted = decrypted_file.read(l)

                decrypted = chacha.decrypt(nonce, encrypted, aad)
                original_file.write(decrypted)

    decrypted_file.close()
    original_file.close()

    os.replace(decFile, file)
```

The above code is the decryption function.

The below code is the `try ... except` block, which gives an error if the password is wrong.

```
try:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = executor.map(decfile, fileList)

    list(result)
    
except:
    print('Wrong Password')
```

Comment: Just are asides: If `decfile` decrypts an encrypted file, then the *file* argument should be referring to the encrypted file, right? Then wouldn't `with open(file, 'rb') as decrypted_file:` make more sense as `with open(file, 'rb') as encrypted_file:`? Also, I don't see where the password enters into this. Also, `decrypted_file.seek(12)` seems to serve no purpose since the prior `read` should have left you at offset 12., right? Now as for your problem perhaps if you posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) things would be clearer.

Comment: But my suggestion to you is that you should write out to your encrypted files as the *initial bytes* something that is fixed length and can uniquely identify it as encrypted file, such as b'I am encrypted'. You should then check the encrypted file for a minimal length (length of the fixed length header + length of the nonce + l_bytes) and if it satisfies that then read in the header to first make sure it is an encrypted file before proceeding. I would also make it `except Exception as e:` so that you can see what the actual exception is.

Comment: In short, I wouldn't be worrying so much as to *why* trying to decrypt an unencrypted file is behaving the way it is. I would just try to detect an unencrypted file. Also catch exceptions in `decfile` so that other submitted tasks can complete.

Comment: As another aside: Unless you have a very special solid-state drive, you probably will not gain anything doing concurrent I/O operations by concurrently decrypting multiple files. In fact, it could even hurt performance.